# Servlets: can't link css from jsp: cannot resolve directory resources: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} links to root instead of src/main/webapp

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets

I have this project structure (`WEB-INF` is inside `src/main/webapp/`):

[image]

I try to access a `login.css` from `login.jsp` using

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/login.css">
```

However Idea underlines it as `cannot resolve directory`:

[image]

I use servlets for this project, but however in the other project that uses `Spring MVC`, the same css link works perfectly. I suspect the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` links to a different folder in this case: to the project root (`../src`) instead of the `root/src/main/webapp` folder.

Is there a way to change where `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` links to? Or some other way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

"resources" looks like a directory for maven or concept/grouping in your IDE. They are probably combined at the root of your WAR> My guess would be that your you should remove "resources" from the link as they really reside at the root of your web app.

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/login.css
```

Take a look at the WAR that is actually produced and where they would be in that.